# C# - Is it possible to pass a derived type from a BaseModel to a Repository<T> that needs the type?

Tags: c#, generics

So I have a Repository class that needs the type.

I have a BaseModel class that my other models are derived from.

Right now I have to have a new Repository() that I call save, update, delete, etc.

I would like to be able to incorporate those methods into the BaseModel, so I can just create an object and call myObject.Save(); which will then call then create the repository and use it.

So essentially I would like to do this:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
    public void Save(T entity)
    {
        // Save Here!
    }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        // This line needs the Type T. How do I pass this?
        using(var repository = new Repository<T>()) {
            repository.Save(this);
        }
    }
}

public class DerivedModel : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note: This is not using Entity Framework.

So the result of this would be

```
var myEntity = new DerivedModel() {
     Name = "My Entity";
};

myEntity.Save();
```

Comment: You should really keep the repository code away from the models.

Comment: I understand that. But I want to break that convention,. Doing it this way will save ridiculous amounts of coding and changes to it will take place in a single place. Which is much easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use reflection to create your repository, you could use the derived type as type parameter to your base class, for example:

```
public class BaseModel<T> // T will be your derived type
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        // T will be your derived type now
        using(var repository = new Repository<T>()) {
            repository.Save(this);
        }
    }
}

public class Repository<T>
{
    // Save method must use base type here
    public void Save(BaseModel<T> item )
    {

    }
}

// BaseModel will get the derived type as type parameter
public class DerivedModel : BaseModel<DerivedModel>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend keeping your repository code away from your models, but if you really want to do it this way, then this will work:

```
public void Save()
{
    //Get the generic type of your model
    var type = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(this.GetType());

    //need dynamic here so we can call arbitrary methods on it later
    dynamic repository = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    //Need to cast to dynamic or you will get an error
    repository.Save((dynamic)this);

}
```